# Python requests SSL ConnectionError: Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am going crazy because I am getting this error while simple ssl request, this is working in different linuxes no problems but not in this Debian setup.

My python requests version is 2.0.1 and I have tested with 1.2.0 and many other things that I read around the net but no luck at all...

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.domain.com')

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.domain.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)
```

Comment: This error is thrown because the remote server is closing the TCP connection without warning. Does this problem occur for all TLS-using websites, or just the one you're interested in?

Comment: This error happens just in certain domains, and in this particular machine...

Comment: Maybe it was sending a malformed request, and the server was rejecting it out of hand? Or the server expected headers that weren't there.